# GA cross domain tracking on a domain with no javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to enable cross domain tracking in Google Analytics (we implement it through Google Tag Manager), but I can't find a way to make it work where a domain has no javascript capabilities.

This is the scenario:

1. User visits several pages in **sub1.domainA.com**,
2. User clicks on a link on **sub1.domainA.com** and is redirected on **sub2.domainA.com** where he visits several pages,
3. User clicks on a link on **sub2.domainA.com** and is redirected on **domainB.com** where he visits several pages,
4. User clicks on a link in **domainB.com** and goes back to **sub1.domainA.com**

The problem is that **sub1.domainA.com** and **sub2.domainA.com** have JS capabilities but **domainB.com** hasn't. I have control on the page sources but I can't use any JS.
I can track successfully points 1 and 2, but the session is lost in point 3 and 4 looks like a new session.

I can't find any documentation of how to make it work in this particular case (i.e. what I should do in pages in **domainB.com**), has anyone already gone through this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add domainB.com to your [referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en) in the property settings it will be ignored and the session will be maintained (unless the user spends so much time on domainB.com that the sessions times out). You do not need to make changes to your code.

And of course actions on domainB.com won't be tracked (but then you knew that), it will simply be ignored. The typical use case for this are payment gateways that do not allow tracking.

This is for Universal Analytics. If you use classic analytics you need to add a special parameter (utm_nooverride=1) to the url on domainB.com that redirects back to domainA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eike. As you said this is a case with a payment gateway (WorldPay specifically). Just to confirm this, are you saying that this is impossible to achieve? If another domain has no JS capabilities, there is no way to track this?

Thank you again.

Comment: In theory you might try to fiddle with the Google Analytics measurement protocol to track domainB (e.g. if you can set an image pixel with custom parameters). In practice the JS tracker does not mix that well with custom implementations and you might inadvertently break the session, so for practical purposes I don't think this will work.

Comment: Thank you again, do you know if this possibility is documented somewhere? I can't find anything useful to understand a bit more the matter.